# # VALUE Error while executing UDF VBA Function on formatted cells

Tags: vba, error-handling, formatting, user-defined-functions

I wrote the following function to check if the prerequisites for my Excel row are satisified.

```vb
Public Function PREREQUISITESOK(prerequisites As Range) As String
    Dim cw As Worksheet
    Dim prerequisite_cell As Range
    Dim prerequisite_cell_txt As String
    Dim training_id_cell As Range
    Dim no_groups_cell_to_compare As Range
    Dim no_groups_cell_to_check As Range
    Dim training_id_cell_txt As String
    Dim training_id_cell_row_n As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    
    Application.Volatile
    
    PREREQUISITESOK = "OK"
    
    Set cw = Sheets("4c.Trainings OSS")
    
    Set training_id = cw.Range("$B$11:$B$34")
    
    Set no_groups_cell_to_compare = cw.Range("J" & CStr(prerequisites.Row))
    
    For Each prerequisite_cell In prerequisites.Cells
        prerequisite_cell_txt = prerequisite_cell.Text
        If prerequisite_cell_txt = "" Then
            Exit For
        Else
            For Each training_id_cell In training_id.Cells
                training_id_cell_txt = training_id_cell.Text
                If training_id_cell_txt = prerequisite_cell_txt Then
                    training_id_cell_row_n = training_id_cell.Row
                    Set no_groups_cell_to_check = cw.Cells(training_id_cell_row_n, no_groups_cell_to_compare.Column)
                    If no_groups_cell_to_check.Value < no_groups_cell_to_compare.Value Then
                        PREREQUISITESOK = "NOT OK"
                        Exit Function 'It is enough for us that one prerequisite is not satisfied so we can exit the function
                    Else
                        PREREQUISITESOK = "OK"
                    End If
                    Exit For 'Training IDs are unique so if we find the right Training ID then we may exit the loop
                End If
            Next training_id_cell
        End If
    Next prerequisite_cell
End Function
```

Note that the `prerequisites` range is inline formatted.

The function that I wrote is supposed to return `String` value so I completely do not understand why am I getting `#VALUE!` error.

What is interesting that if I clear formatting from the `prerequisites` cells that are used as arguments of the function then `#VALUE!` error disappears.

Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: Have you tried `.value` instead of `.text`?   Also, not sure of the need to convert `prerequisites.Row` to string

Comment: Thanks a lott @Nathan_Sav !
It actually works with `.value`. I wonder why? Is it like this that if a cell is formatted then its `.text` value is not recognized properly?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.text